# How to show validation errors in the single message Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, validation, message, show

I have a problem with codeigniter, when checking the fields it shows errors as follows:

```
The Username field is required. The Password field is required. 
The Another field is required
```

but I need it so like this:

```
Required fields a Username, Password, Another.
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do that. But you have numerous number of choices. For example: don't use form validation library at all or develop your own. Try something like this:

```
$errorArray = array();
if (!$this->input->post('username')) {
    $errorArray[] = 'Username';
}
if (!$this->input->post('Password')) {
    $errorArray[] = 'Password';
}
if (count($errorArray)!==0) {
    $allErrorFields = implode(",", $errorArray);
    $errorMessage = 'Required fields: '.$allErrorFields;
    $data['errorMessage'] = $errorMessage;
}

$this->load->view('myview', $data);
```